# how to copy the whole column to another column starting from a certain row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently doing a macro to copy the whole column from one worksheet to another column starting from row 2 in another worksheet. However I don't think it's working, `Set des = Sheets(3).Range("P2:P" & Rows(i))` this is the line causes error.

```
Sub Sample()
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim CopyRange As Range
Dim rw As Range
Dim rw1 As Range
Dim rw2 As Range
Dim rw3 As Range
Dim des As Range
Dim des1 As Range
Dim des2 As Range
Dim des3 As Range
'~~> Change Sheet1 to relevant sheet name
With Sheets(1)
    lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value)) <> 0 Then
            If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
                Set CopyRange = .Rows(i)
            Else
                Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, .Rows(i))
                Set rw = .Columns(16)
                Set rw1 = .Columns(23)
                Set rw2 = .Columns(3)
                Set rw3 = .Columns(18)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If Not CopyRange Is Nothing Then
        Set des = Sheets(3).Range("P2:P" & Rows(i))
        Set des1 = Sheets(3).Columns("R")
        Set des2 = Sheets(3).Columns("T")
        Set des3 = Sheets(3).Columns("U")
        '~~> Change Sheet2 to relevant sheet name
        rw.Copy des
        rw1.Copy des1
        rw2.Copy des2
        rw3.Copy des3

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the copied columns to ranges to paste them properly like this:

```
Sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row).Copy ' this code copies from first to last cell with data in column A
```

then later on you need to paste them with e.g.

```
sheets(3).range("R2").paste
```

Comment: The error message of `Application-defined or object-defined error` occurs at line `Set des1 = Sheets(3).Columns("R2:R" & i)`

Comment: yes this is because you are referring to column and you give a range type of address column address cant be "R2:R" you should put .range("R2:R" & i)

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice this, but now it says `it can't paste because the copy area aren't the same size` at `rw.Copy des`

Comment: okay my bad, actually you need to specify just start of the range in pasting, just .range("R2") should be sufficient

Comment: so it should be Set des1 = Sheets(2).Range("R2")? Since I want to paste over another column starting from row 2, will this line be able to do that?

Comment: I have tried with what I typed in the previous comment and it doesn't work :(

Comment: I think you should change the copied columns to ranges instead, get the first cell of column and last one into a range address and copy that

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, sorry for the reply as I had been trying with your code, I put both line under else section, but unfortunately the error message `object doesn't support this method or property`. I'm sorry I've been confused with this, and clueless now.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I dont have enough post to comment directly to KKowalczyk's answer.

Cause you loop i through all the For loop, therefore at the time you set the des range, i = lastrow + 1. ds range will be from P2 to P-(lastrow+1)

In the meanwhile, the rw range from A2 to A-lastrow.

Therefore the size of 2 range are different. You should change the code to:

```
Set des = Sheets(3).Range("P2:P" & Rows(i-1))
```

Comment: this wont work, rows(I-1) will return error wrong type

Comment: use the updated answer of mine to copy the columns, then the paste with .range("R2") will work